# Snapshot a database by creating a copy

Tags: postgresql

As part of backup script I want to create a consistent backup of my application and database by stopping the service and then creating snapshots of database and file system.

With PostgreSQL I can create a copy of database easily by using the database as a template in a create database command.

Is this a valid way to create a snapshot of a PostgreSQL database? Is it for example quick? Quicker than using pg_dump for example?

Comment: By stopping the service and just creating a copy you're already not really creating a snapshot. It is a valid solution though. See also [Is it possible to quickly create/restore database snapshots with PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/is-it-possible-to-quickly-create-restore-database-snapshots-with-postgresql).

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why is this not a type of snapshot? The article of the link you share also names it that way.

Comment: A snapshot is a particular type of mechanism. As the other questions highlights it's usually based on a filesystem level mechanism/VM level. One of the main features is that you'd usually transparently be able to role back. If you need to stop your applications, shutdown your system and create a distinct file copy named "Database Backup <date>.tar.gz" that's a backup, not a snapshot.